# How to RESPOND to a click event on an input type=file in non IE browsers

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, file-upload, input

So here's the scenario-

Unlike the 3000 other questions on StackOverflow about how to INVOKE the click event on an input[type=file] element, I just want to respond to it. I'm looking for something like:

```
<input id="theFile" onclick="var that=this;setTimeout(function(){if(that.value){postTheForm();}}),0);" />
```

I'm not trying to call click() on the element, I just want to know when someone has selected a file so it we can submit the form. In IE, it works as expected, because the file dialog box sleeps the javascript thread until the user clicks Open or Cancel in the dialog. In FireFox, it seems like the dialog does not sleep the thread, and the anonymous function fires immediately - even while the dialog is still up.

I was thinking may I could use the onchange event, or something else in FireFox to simulate the IE behavior, but haven't had any luck so far. Any ideas as to how I can execute code AFTER the user clicks Open or Cancel in the dialog?

Comment: you can focus the control and then when the dialog is closed you can respond to the blur event of the file upload control. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use: `onchange="submitForm()"`

Comment: WOW! I just realized that my test case for this was messed up and I wasn't wiring up the event handler correctly when I ran this test case. I tested this in FF3.6, IE9, IE6, and Chrome and it works in all of them. I can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I love it when the most simple solution actually WORKS!

Answer (score 1):

When you click the file upload tell jQuery to focus it, when you select a file and click open/cancel it will lose focus aka `blur`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").click(function() {
        $(this).focus();
    });
    $("#fileUpload").blur(function() {
        alert("blurred");
    });
});
```

I tested this in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could start up an interval timer to just check every 100 milliseconds or so.

```
$('input:file').click(function() {
  var file = this, form = this.form, val = this.value, interval;
  function checkValue() {
    if (file.value !== val) {
      cancelInterval(interval);
      form.submit();
    }
  }
  interval = setInterval(checkValue, 100);
});
```

Thing is, this is a little fragile because the "value" of a file input is not a complete path. However, since you're submitting the whole form anyway, the user really doesn't have a chance to click on the file element more than once.

*edit* — this is presuming that the "change" event really isn't working for you; I don't have Firefox available at the moment to see.